# How to change the default link for "Contact person by email" generated by the "Email contact form" field display?

Tags: forms, emails

I have a content type set up with an email field that displays a link to a contact form. I want to alter the link from something like this:

```
<a href="email/node/421/field_contact">Contact person by email</a>
```

to something like this:

```
<a class="colorbox-node" href="email/node/421/field_contact?width=600&height=600">Contact person by email</a>
```

That way the link will popup into a modal instead of going to a new page. I have the requisite modules installed to render the modal and can do it manually in the content area of a node, I just haven't figured out how to apply the class and dimension info to a field link.